# absolute position of a div on firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a div with fixed width and height. i am trying to positioning it at a fixed place on my wp post but in chrome it seems to be ok but on mozilla it's about 30 pixels upper.

i am using this div inisde my wp posts

any suggestions?

my div

```
<div style="height:579px;width:350px;position:absolute;z-index:999999999; top: 0; left: 0; margin-left: 13%; margin-top:49%;">
```

Thanks

Comment: try using position: relative. The absolute positioning may cause the differences.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: `margin-top:49%;` can you use fix values instead of `%`? It might solve it

Comment: try using svg width for mozilla

Comment: just to understand well; your absolute div is inside a relative container? why don't you use left: 13% and top:49%?

Comment: are you using css reset code to reset browser specific styles..?